# MediaWiki Server does not display correctly

Tags: mediawiki

I have a mediawiki server and when I open it, it looks like this
[image]
This is a brand new mediawiki server and I just finished setting it up.

My LocalSettings.php is at https://voidtm.tk/LocalSettings.php

How can I fix this?

Comment: Open browser console. It looks like missing or wrong css path

Comment: @ArunSharma the only thing in the browser console is a 404 for favicon.ico

Answer (score 0):

You should configure a skin. I suggest using [the most common skin known as vector](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Skin:Vector). That page also has installation instructions.